# In a loop - match 'i' with an index value from a csv (Python/Networkx)

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7, csv, networkx

I'm currently trying to draw some edges in Networkx, my nodes have 2 patch properties, position and status which are used in a colonisation simulation algorithm. I've been trying to scale up my simulation which has meant turning away from working out euclidean distances between my nodes (and also away from code that works!).

I have a csv of the row number index of the nearest neighbours of each node, this index corresponding to the row of another csv which has the 3d co-ordinates of the nodes contained. i.e., on the nearest neighbour csv on row 0 may have 3 nearest neighbours on the same row in separate columns so it would be 0, 56, 76 if node 0 had nearest neighbours in node 56 and 76 which would correspond to rows 0, 56 and 76 on the co-ord csv.

I then need to draw edges between these nearest neighbour nodes for my algorithm to play with the nodes. So I have some pseudo-code:

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
from sklearn.neighbors import BallTree
import csv
from itertools import izip_longest
import pandas as pd

density = 0.14 #Stellar density per cubic parsec
L = 100

Patches = int(0.056*density*L**3+15)
P_init = 0.0001   # Probability that a patch will be occupied at the beginning
Distance = 10

dat = np.random.uniform(low = -1, high = 1, size = (Patches,3)) * L

np.savetxt('nearand1.csv', dat, delimiter = ',')

nearand = np.genfromtxt('nearand1.csv', delimiter = ',',usecols=np.arange(0, 3))

tree = BallTree(nearand, leaf_size=2)
ind = tree.query_radius(nearand, r=10)
df = pd.DataFrame(ind)
df.to_csv('bobbington4.csv',sep='e',index=False, header=False)

xcoord = nearand[:,0]
ycoord = nearand[:,1]
zcoord = nearand[:,2]

bobbington = np.genfromtxt('bobbington4.csv', delimiter = ',', dtype = 'int')
bobbington0 = bobbington[:,0]
bobbington1 = bobbington[:,1]
bobbington2 = bobbington[:,2]
bobbington3 = bobbington[:,3]
bobbington4 = bobbington[:,4]
bobbington5 = bobbington[:,5]
bobbington6 = bobbington[:,6]
bobbington7 = bobbington[:,7]
bobbington8 = bobbington[:,8]
bobbington9 = bobbington[:,9]
bobbington10 = bobbington[:,10]
bobbington11 = bobbington[:,11]
bobbington12 = bobbington[:,12]
bobbington13 = bobbington[:,13]


class patch:
        def __init__(self,status=0,pos=(0,0,0)):
        self.status = status
        self.pos = pos
    def __str__(self):
        return(str(self.status))

G = nx.Graph()

for i in xrange(Patches):

    Stat = 1 if np.random.uniform() < P_init else 0
    Pos  = (xcoord[i], ycoord[i], zcoord[i])
    G.add_node(patch(Stat,Pos))

for i in G.nodes():
    for j in G.nodes():
        if i.pos where i == bobbington0:   
            if j.pos where j == bobbington1:
                G.add_edge(i,j)   

pos = {}
for n in G.nodes():
   pos[n] = n.pos


occup = [n.status for n in G]   

Time = [0]
Occupancy = [np.sum([n.status for n in G])/float(Patches)]
```

Here bobbington0 is just a column of node indices going from 0 -> 7854 and bibbington1 is the first nearest neighbour for each of those nodes. What is is the best way to go about this? I'm struggling to find anything on this type of problem but I'm probably wording things poorly.
Thanks in advance for any help you can give me.

Comment: I have just looked at some of your previous questions, and many of them, including this one, would benefit greatly from a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: I've added in the most compact code which will perform the minimum needed. Thank you for your advice, does seem like there is quite a lot however. Also this would only draw the edges for the first nearest neighbours, but once the first is working, the rest will follow

Comment: Are you missing a `pandas` import in your example? (I ask because of `pd.DataFrame`.)

Comment: I haven't taken the time to fully understand what you're trying to do, but one of the first things experienced programmers will notice about your example is that you've got `bobbington0` through `bobbington13` as separate variables. This is usually not the best approach, as it is both cumbersome and limiting. Most likely, it would be better to build a list instead.

Comment: As for your specific task, it sounds like each node could have a variable number of nearest neighbors. That is, one row could have a single neighbor while another row could have three neighbors or even 10 neighbors. So I would think you should process each row fully before moving on to the next row, rather than processing by column.

Comment: @JohnY @StephenRauch thank you for your feedback and time, yes `pandas` is missing. Making a list is what I'm doing in my personal test code, I just wanted the example here to be as clear as possible. Also with the variable nearest neighbours, you are correct, the 13 columns in the maximum number of nearest neighbours I find. My plan was to find a way to ignore the blank columns (which show as -1 when you print), as I'm not certain how I would evaluate N number of rows in a general fashion (I have a feeling this is glaringly obvious but I've hit a wall!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it. Not particularly elegant but it works.

```
for i in G.nodes():
    for j in G.nodes():
        diff1 = j.boba[0] - i.bubu
        if diff1 == 0:
            G.add_edge(i, j)
```